# Different val accuracy by fit() and evaluate() in Keras with the same validation set

Tags: python, keras, stack

I am using keras to train a stacking network;
sub-models includ InceptionV3,resnet50 and Xception.
in these sub-models: fit val accuracy is same to evaluate val accuracy.
but when after stacking these sub-model,I get a fantastic result that fit val accuracy is higher 1% than evaluate val accuracy.
I split data 60% train set 20% validation set 20% test set.
What did I do wrong?

when fit() with validation set:

```
    Epoch 126/250
216/216 [==============================] - 4s 17ms/step - loss: 0.8279 - accuracy: 0.6574
```

when evaluate() with validation set:

```
Val loss: 0.8272405112231219
Val accuracy: 0.6435185074806213
```

Comment: What do you mean fit and evaluate? You passed the training set to fix, and then training set to evaluate? In that case you won't get the same values, fit uses a running mean of batches as weights change, evaluate uses fixed weights

Comment: The metrics printed while the epoch is running are averaged values. I.e. they are calculated separately on each batch and then divided by the number of batches.

When you run `evaluate()` afterwards it does a more accurate calculation